# Decode bitmap returns null

Tags: android, bitmap, decode

I decode bitmap from file or file descriptor always return `null` in Android 11. In lower android version it works normally.
In my case, i take a photo by devices, and save it to temp file, then i decode it.

`BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath)`
or
    `BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(filePath)`

also return `null`.
Please give me the solutions.
Thank you!

Comment: `i take a photo by devices, and save it to temp file,` I have no idea what you are doing. Please elaborate. Also tell how you obtained file path. And tell which path it is exactly.

Comment: @blackapps Thank for reply, Everything works, but I updated from targetSdk 29 to 30,  and decodeFile return null

Comment: `I have no idea what you are doing.`

Comment: `     val bitmap = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val pfd = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
            pfd?.fileDescriptor?.getBitmapFromFileDes()
        } else {
            photoPath.getBitmapFromPath()
        }`
This is my code.

Comment: Please post your code in your post and not as comment. And start telling how you obtained that uri.